# How can I ensure Dispose() is called on an advanced function's local variable on stop signal?

Tags: powershell, idisposable, powershell-cmdlet, object-lifetime

I have noticed that objects implementing `IDisposable` in advanced functions aren't reliably disposed of when a "stop" signal (eg. pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) is sent during execution.  This is a pain when the object holds a handle to, for example, a file.  If the stop signal is received at an inopportune time, the handle doesn't get closed and the file remains locked until the PowerShell session is closed.

Consider the following class and functions:

```
class f : System.IDisposable {
    Dispose() { Write-Host 'disposed' }
}

function g {
    param( [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]$InputObject )
    begin { $f = [f]::new() }
    process {
        try { 
            $InputObject
        }
        catch {
            $f.Dispose()
            throw
        }
    }
    end {$f.Dispose()}
}

function throws {
    param ( [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)] $InputObject )
    process { throw 'something' }
}

function blocks {
    param ( [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)] $InputObject )
    process { Wait-Event 'bogus' }
}
```

Imagine `$f` holds a handle to a file and releases it when its `Dispose()` method is called.  My goal is that the lifetime of `$f` matches the lifetime of `g`.  `$f` is disposed correctly when `g` is invoked in each the following ways:

```
g
'o' | g
'o' | g | throws
```

I can tell as much because each of these outputs `disposed`.

When the stop signal is sent while execution is occuring downstream of `g`, however, `$f` is not disposed.  To test that, I invoked

```
'o' | g | blocks
```

which blocks at the `Wait-Event` inside `blocks`, then I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to stop execution.  In that case, `Dispose()` does not seem to get called (or, at least `disposed` is not written to the console).

In C# implementations of such functions it is my understanding that [`StopProcessing()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.cmdlet.stopprocessing?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0#System_Management_Automation_Cmdlet_StopProcessing) gets called on a stop signal to do such cleanup.  However, there seems to be no analog to `StopProcessing` available for PowerShell implementations of advanced functions.

How can I ensure that `$f` is disposed in all cases including a stop signal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### You can't if the function accepts pipeline input.

I don't think a robust way of achieving this is possible if the function accepts pipeline input.  The reason is that any of the following could occur while code is executing upstream in the pipeline:

- `break`, `continue`, or `throw`
- terminating error
- stop signal received

When these occur upstream, no part of the function can be caused to intervene.  The `begin{}` and `process{}` blocks have either run to completion or not run at all, and the `end{}` block may or may not be run.  The closest to an on-point solution I have found is the following:

```
function g {
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        $InputObject 
    )
    begin { $f = [f]::new() } # The local IDisposable is created when the pipeline is established.
    process {
        try 
        {
            # flags to keep track of why finally was run
            $success = $false
            $caught = $false

            $InputObject  # output an object to exercise the pipeline downstream

            # if we get here, nothing unusual happened downstream
            $success = $true
        }
        catch
        {
            # we get here if an exception was thrown
            $caught = $true

            # !!!
            # This is bad news.  It's possible the exception will be 
            # handled by an upstream process{} block.  The pipeline would
            # survive and the next invocation of process{} would occur
            # after $f is disposed.
            # !!!
            $f.Dispose()

            # rethrow the exception
            throw
        }
        finally
        {
            # !!!
            # This finally block is not invoked when the PowerShell instance receives
            # a stop signal while executing code upstream in the pipeline.  In that
            # situation cleanup $f.Dispose() is not invoked.
            # !!!
            if ( -not $success -and -not $caught )
            {
                # dispose only if finally{} is the only block remaining to run
                $f.Dispose()
            }
        }
    }
    end {$f.Dispose()}
}
```

However, per the comments there are still cases where `$f.Dispose()` is not invoked.  You can step through [this working example that includes such cases](https://gist.github.com/alx9r/f81cf64f50a016edda4e92968bdb9c3b).

#### Consider a pattern like `usingObject {}` instead.

If we limit usage to the case where the function responsible for cleanup does not accept pipeline input, then we can factor out the lifetime-management logic into a helper function similar to C#'s `using` block.  [Here is a proof-of-concept that implements such a helper function called `usingObject`.](https://gist.github.com/alx9r/a52d1432f443672eeb2cd99707a076d7)  This is an example of how `g` could be substantially simplified when using `usingObject` to achieve robust invokation of `.Dispose()`:

```
# refactored function g
function g {
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        $InputObject,

        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [f]
        $f
    )
    process {
        $InputObject
    }
}

# usages of function g
usingObject { [f]::new() } {
    g -f $_
}

usingObject { [f]::new() } {
    'o' | g -f $_
}

try
{
    usingObject { [f]::new() } {
        'o' | g -f $_ | throws
    }
}
catch {}

usingObject { [f]::new() } {
    'o' | g -f $_ | blocks
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you can just add a finally{} block and dispose it there. You might also want to consider setting your ErrorActionPreference, since you are doing custom error handling.

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'

try
{
    try
    {
        1/0
    }
    catch
    {
        throw New-Object System.Exception("Exception!")
    }
    finally
    {
        "You can dispose here!"
    }
}
catch
{
    $_.Exception.Message | Write-Output
}
```

Comment: I thought that at first too.  The problem is that that `finally` will run on each invokation of `process{}` so the object will already be disposed and unusable for anything but the first instance of `$InputObject` in the pipeline.  In other words, `'a','b' | g` outputs `a dispose b dispose` when it needs to be `a b dispose`.